# filter an array javascript that start with "J"

Tags: javascript

I am trying create a function that takes an array of names, and returns an array of only those names that start with "J";

Below is what I have but it returns everything else.

```
var names = ["john", "sat", "james", "mark"];

function filterNames(array) {

    var namesNew = names.filter(function (item) {
       return item.indexOf("j");
    });

    return namesNew;
}
```

Comment: try `return item.toLowerCase().indexOf("j") === 0;`

Comment: Did you read the [documentation for `indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)? That's usually a good place to start. By the way, what's the intent of your `filterNames` function taking an `array` parameter that is never used?

Comment: @haxxxton Wouldn't `item.toLowerCase()[0] === 'j'` be slightly preferable?

Comment: @torazaburo, you're correct, i was going for trying to show how to do it with `indexOf` :)

Comment: Try `function filterNames(array) { return array.filter(([firstChar]) => firstChar === 'j'); }`.

Answer (score 0):

Try `return item.indexOf("j") == 0;`

indexOf returns the position of the character in the item.

Answer (score 0):

this code may help u.

```
var names = ["john", "sat", "James", "mark"];
var arrLen = names.length;
for (var i=0; i<arrLen; i++) {
    for (var j=0; j<names[i].length; j++) {
        var asciiNum = names[i].charCodeAt(j);
        if (asciiNum === 74 || asciiNum === 106) {
        console.log(names[i]);   // john, James
    }
}
```

OR
`return !item.indexOf("j");`

Comment: Why on earth would you use character codes? Also, your code logs any entry with a "J" anywhere in it, not just the first character. Finally, his question stated he wants to return an array, not log matches.

Comment: sorry.my English is not very well.But in my code, all the things that you say can be done.I want to send a thinking what I know